# Display Custom Error Page for All Errors in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a few sites in my IIS including ASP.Net and PHP. I want to define a custom pages for error handling that I can configure in IIS and it displays on errors occuring in all the sites. Say for example if error 500 is occured it displays an ASP.Net page having detailed error info of what happened actually. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. = (

**PHP**

For your PHP sites, there are different solutions including error-logging plugins, but the standard one involves the built-in functionality of PHP's error handling. See here: http://www.nyphp.org/PHundamentals/7_PHP-Error-Handling

**ASP.NET**

For ASP.NET sites, this is the default behavior of the IIS error page. It will show you the exact error code, stack trace, and offending lines of code. If you wanted to, you could create your own application-level error handler to handle any and all exceptions that can occur inside your site; usually this is used to hide the nasty error message and show the user a friendlier, less-scary message instead. You can certainly re-use the code in all your different ASP.NET sites. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5977/Global-Error-Handling-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Thats helpful but I'm thinking in these lines.
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors
What if in step 5 and 6 in "How to" section I configure a separate web application that has a single page and somehow get the error details from IIS.